# Ng-admin custom reference list - with ability to create new entry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-admin

I'm trying to figure out how I can make  a custom directive which will combine:

1. reference list select field
2. create button which will show a reference entity creation view
3. and on creation save. reload reference list entities, so i can choose a newly created entity.

It can be easily done using completely custom code, but i want to make it using ng-admin templates and directives.

It's also quite common functionality, but i'm having a hard time integrating it into ng-admin.

So in case there is no required field in list, i will not loose data i already entered by navigating to create new entity on another page.

Answer (score 0):

Add two fields:

- one of type `referenced_list` to display related entries
- one virtual field with an empty label and a custom template, using a create button with prefilled default values for the related entry (e.g. `<ma-create-button entity-name="comments" default-values="{ post_id: entry.values.id }" size="xs"></ma-create-button>`)

Check https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin-demo/blob/3a0944acbcb12dc20dc8a4a860c6c9f8da9c1645/js/customers/config.js#L81-L101 for an example.